# Order Weekday by order in ggplot2/R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

The below dataset is categorized by weekdays.

```
> member_casual   weekday  count
1        casual Wednesday 218101
2        casual   Tuesday 214898
3        casual    Sunday 403728
4        casual  Saturday 468259
5        casual    Friday 289970
6        casual  Thursday 224154
```

When I plot this in bar graph the weekdays are not in chronological order:

```
  chart <- ggplot(member_causal_weekly, aes(x=weekday, y=count, fill=weekday))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap(~member_casual)+
  geom_text(aes(label=count), vjust=1.6, color="white", size=3)+
  theme (axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnDhu.png)

Comment: You will need modify ``member_causal_weekly`` and set ``weekday`` as a factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reorder factor levels:

```
  member_causal_weekly$weekday <- factor(member_causal_weekly$weekday,
    levels = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"))

  chart <- ggplot(member_causal_weekly, aes(x=weekday, y=count, fill=weekday))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap(~member_casual)+
  geom_text(aes(label=count), vjust=1.6, color="white", size=3)+
  theme (axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))
```